# how to add integer elements in char array in java

Tags: java

```
String st="1a2b3j4";

char ar[]=st.toCharArray();

int sum=ar[0]+ar[2];//how to add the numbers
```

when i try to add its taking ASCII values

how to convert chat'1' to integer

Comment: What does this have to do with C++, Spring, Hibernate, and Java EE?

Comment: //how to convert char '1' and  '2' to integers ?

Comment: Are you looking for `Integer.parseInt(value)`? I'm rather confused what the actual question is, sorry.

Comment: Consider the distance from any digit to `'0'`.

Comment: Use loop, it will make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

You just must convert the character to String and then use something like this:

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(stringNum1) + Integer.parseInt(stringNum2);
```

Comment: this will raise `NumberFormatException` if `stringNum1` or `stringNum2` is an alphabet. you need to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
String st = "1a2b3j4";
char ar[] = st.toCharArray();
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    sum += (ar[i] - '0');
}
System.out.println(sum); // prints 167 (1 + 49 + 2 + 50 + 3 + 58 + 4)
```

If you want to consider the ASCII value for the alphabets but the numeric digits itself, then you can try as following.

```
String st = "1a2b3j4";
char ar[] = st.toCharArray();
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i] >= '0' && ar[i] <= '9') {
        sum += (ar[i] - '0');
    } else {
        sum += ar[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(sum); // prints 311 (1 + 97 + 2 + 98 + 3 + 106 + 4)
```

Note that, ASCII values for `1,a,2,b,3,j,4` are `49,97,50,98,51,106,52`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert character  ASCII numeric value, just cast your `char` as an `int`

```
like char character = arr[0];    
int asciiValue = (int) character;
```

Comment: That will get the ASCII value, not the numeric "digit" value.

Answer (score -1):

just add (int) at the beginning of each array elements.
ie int sum=(int)ar[0]+(int)ar[2];
hope this helps;

Comment: Please try to markdown your code and provide more information for further detail.